# Time Touch Events Take in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, view, touch

I am wondering how I would go about measuring the time in between touches inside a view in the iPhone SDK.  I know that the first event triggered is touchesBegan: and then the last one triggered is touchesEnded:, however I just don't know how I would go about measuring the time that the user has touched the view for.  For instance, if they keep their finder in the view for 2 seconds, it will automatically trigger function twoSeconds: or something like that.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[NSDate date]` to get the current date and time. Store it in `touchesBegan:`, and fetch the duration in `touchesEnded:` as this

```
NSTimeInterval duration = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:beganDate];
```

You will now have the duration between the events measured in seconds in `length`.

Comment: Hi PeyloW: Thanks for your reply. This sounds like a great way to measure the time. However, in addition to this, would there be some way to automatically preform a task if the user has touched inside the view for a certain amount of time without needing them to release their finder.

Comment: You could call performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: in touchesBegan:, and then do cancelPreviousPerformRequestWithTarget: in touchesEnded:.